# Issues with TexelFetch and "Scalar Swizzle" in GLSL

Tags: opengl, glsl, shader

I have done some work with shaders before but I would consider myself relatively inexperienced with GLSL. I am trying to write a fluid solver that simulates smoke using a series of fragment shaders. Most of these involve taking discrete samples from the texture and then doing some operation onh them, so they all have similar compilation errors. Every pixel, and only each pixel, must be evaluated so I am using texelFetch as opposed to texture2D for my sampling. The following is an example of such a fragment shader:

```
uniform sampler2D velocity;
uniform sampler2D pressure;
uniform sampler2D solid;
uniform float numCellsX;
uniform float numCellsY;

void main(void) {
    ivec2 pos = ivec2(gl_FragCoord.xy);
    if (texelFetch(solid, pos.xy, 0).x > 0.0)
        discard;

    float c = texelFetch(pressure, pos.xy, 0).x;
    float up = texelFetchOffset(pressure, pos.xy, 0, ivec2(0, 1)).x;
    float down = texelFetchOffset(pressure, pos.xy, 0, ivec2(0, -1)).x;
    float left = texelFetchOffset(pressure, pos.xy, 0, ivec2(-1, 0)).x;
    float right = texelFetchOffset(pressure, pos.xy, 0, ivec2(1, 0)).x;

    float upS = texelFetchOffset(solid, pos.xy, 0, ivec2(0, 1)).x;
    float downS = texelFetchOffset(solid, pos.xy, 0, ivec2(0, -1)).x;
    float leftS = texelFetchOffset(solid, pos.xy, 0, ivec2(-1, 0)).x;
    float rightS = texelFetchOffset(solid, pos.xy, 0, ivec2(1, 0)).x;

    if (upS > 0.0) up = c;
    if (downS > 0.0) down = c;
    if (leftS > 0.0) left = c;
    if (rightS > 0.0) right = c;

    gl_FragColor = texelFetch(velocity, pos.xy, 0) - vec2(0.5 * numCellsX * (right - left), 0.5 * numCellsY * (up - down));
}
```

And when I run this through glSlangValidator, I get the following errors:

```
ERROR: 0:14: 'texelFetch' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:14: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:17: 'texelFetch' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:17: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:18: 'texelFetchOffset' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:18: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:19: 'texelFetchOffset' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:19: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:20: 'texelFetchOffset' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:20: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:21: 'texelFetchOffset' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:21: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:23: 'texelFetchOffset' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:23: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:24: 'texelFetchOffset' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:24: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:25: 'texelFetchOffset' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:25: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:26: 'texelFetchOffset' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:26: 'scalar swizzle' : not supported with this profile: es
ERROR: 0:33: 'texelFetch' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:33: 'assign' :  cannot convert from 'temp 2-component vector of float'
to 'fragColor mediump 4-component vector of float FragColor'
ERROR: 23 compilation errors.  No code generated.
```

There is pretty much an error on almost every line and I have found very little information online about these things. Per the GLSL reference manual:

```
gvec4 texelFetch(gsampler2D sampler, ivec2 P, int lod);
```

I don't quite understand why it isn't accepting my texelFetch calls. I also don't know what scalar swizzle is (can't find this anywhere online) or why its an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> not supported with this profile: es

Perhaps you should compile it with the desktop version of GLSL, instead of GLSL ES (presumably 2.0). You should *always* use a `#version` declaration in your GLSL shaders.

Also, if you're using `texelFetch`, why are you still writing to deprecated outputs like `gl_FragColor`?

However:

> cannot convert from 'temp 2-component vector of float'

That's true regardless of the version for this line:

```
texelFetch(velocity, pos.xy, 0) - vec2(0.5 * numCellsX * (right - left), 0.5 * numCellsY * (up - down))
```

`texelFetch` returns a 4-element vector. You cannot subtract a 2 element vector from a 4-element vector.

Comment: I suppose I should have mentioned, I'm targeting WebGL so I had assumed ES was the right choice. Does WebGL not support texelFetch? And if not, how can I get the exact position of the center of each pixel in normalized texture coordinates?

Comment: @JoshuaDotson: "*Does WebGL not support texelFetch?*" WebGL is based on OpenGL ES 2.0, and that is based, in the main, on desktop GL 2.1. `texelFetch` wasn't introduced until desktop GL version 3.0. As for your other question, that's best asked as a proper question. Though you should probably search first, since I'm fairly sure it's been answered before.

Answer (score 0):

For those reading this, I just had this error and the problem was that I was using .r on a float.

```
float x = texture(...).r;
float y = x.r; // <- This was the problem
```

I just removed the .r and the problem was solved :)